# Creating logz.io alert with regex (or custom logic on log fields)

Tags: regex, kibana, alerts, logz.io

I'm trying to create an alert that has regex in its query/filter parameters
I have the following log lines

```
[2022-05-01 00:00:00] [Thread-1] ERROR MyLoggerName - Iteration #0.  [123456, 456789]  -  2 missing data lines in iteration
[2022-05-01 00:01:00] [Thread-1] ERROR MyLoggerName - Iteration #1.  [234567, 567890]  -  951 missing data lines in iteration
```

According to the following [logz.io documentation](https://logz.io/blog/kibana-advanced/) this is what i entered in the search bar:

```
message:/(.*) (\d{1,19}) missing data lines in iteration/
```

Which yielded no results. If i search for

```
message:"missing data lines in iteration"
```

I get exactly the above log lines so i thought that there was something wrong with my regex but when i tryed online regex engines - i saw that the text was matched.
What is the correct way/format you can pass a regex to match log lines?

The reason for this specific regex is that i would "capture" a part of a log line (in this example, the number 2 and the number 951) and create an alert in logz.io according to some logic on these values. Is this possible? If not - i can adjust the regex to match only numbers i would like to raise an alert on.

Comment: You have a typo in the pattern `iteration` != `interation` See https://regex101.com/r/34FFbk/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird - the typo was in the question. my log lines and regex pattern are correct (and fixed in the question)

Answer (score 0):

To capture only `2` and `951` you should make the first group non-capturable

```
(?:.*) (\d{1,19}) missing data lines in iteration
```

Please see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dnlxxd/1)